# Rails 5 ActiveRecord, how to include fields from associated tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

With Rails 5, Given the models:

```
chef_positions
* id
* name

skills
* id
* name

chef_position_skills
* id
* chef_position_id
* skill_id
```

I have a controller method to return the chef_position_skills by chef_position_id:

```
  def index
    chef_position = ChefPosition.find(params[:chef_position_id])
    render json: chef_position.chef_position_skills
  end
```

This returns:

```
 [{"id":1,"chef_position_id":2,"skill_id":1,"created_at":"2017-06-05T15:44:06.821Z","updated_at":"2017-06-05T15:44:06.821Z"},{"id":2,"chef_position_id":2,"skill_id":2,"created_at":"2017-06-05T15:44:06.821Z","updated_at":"2017-06-05T15:44:06.821Z"}]
```

How can I get the controller to do the following:

1. include skill.name for each record
2. Do not include the timestamps

Comment: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder - part of Rails 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to associate the two first if you haven't already, in your model,  `chef_positions.rb`

```
has_many :skills, through: :chef_position_skills
```

Then in your controller,

```
ChefPosition.where(id: params[:chef_position_id]).joins(:skills).select('chef_positions.id, skills.name')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def index
  chef_position = ChefPosition.find(params[:chef_position_id])
  render json: chef_position.chef_position_skills.map(&:json_data)
end

# ChefPositionSkill#json_data
def json_data
  to_json(
    include: { skill: { only: [:name] } },
    only: [:id, :chef_position_id, :skill_id]
  )
end
```

Define a method `json_data` (just for convenience), and use `.map` to call it for each `chef_position_skill`.

The `include` and `only` are standard json serializer methods, which assist rails in what needs to be included.

The only drawback (as far as I see), is that now you will have another attribute `"skill": { "name": "skill_name" }` in your final json.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
render json: chef_position.chef_position_skills.
  map {|s| s.slice(:id, :chef_position_id, :skill_id).merge s.skill.slice(:name) }
```

I don't have the same models but here is a similar example:

```
irb(main):026:0> u.slice(:id, :email).merge u.funds.slice(:min)
=> {"id"=>1, "email"=>"test@example.com", "min"=>1000000}
```

But I think you'll really like JBuilder which is included in Rails 5.

https://github.com/rails/jbuilder